# Print keys for certain value

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a hash that looks similar to:

```
hash = {key1: true, key2: false, key3: false, key4: true}
```

and I would like to iterate through the hash and print each key which has a `true` value. The result should look like:

```
key1 
key4
```

How am I going to do that? I tried:

```
hash.each do |k,v|
  puts k if true
end
```

Comment: You don't use the value `v` in your loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While iterating is fine, the goal might be achieved in more rubyish manner:

```
 hash.select { |_, v| v }.keys
```

or, if equality to `true` (as an opposite to being just truthy) is significant:

```
 hash.select { |_, v| v == true }.keys
```

To print the result out:

```
 puts hash.select { |_, v| v == true }.keys
```

Further information on how [`Hash#select`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-select) works.

To print all the keys matched as “key1 and key4”:

```
puts hash.select { |_, v| v == true }.keys.join(' and ')
```

Comment: To get the result the question author asks for we need `puts hash.select { |_, v| v }.keys`

Comment: @mudasobwa I'm a ruby beginner and have literally no idea what's happening within the brackets.

Comment: Within the brackets there is a so-called block, passed to `select` iteration. Select method will call a block on each element in hash, passing `key`-`value` pair to the block. Whether a block returns `true`, the element is to be kept in the resulted array. Please see the update to the answer.

Comment: Just a query on your use of `_`? Is there any reason for using this particular character? Thanks

Comment: @sagarpandya82 Yes. Many. — Memory is not allocated for this variable, — One might use many underscores within same codeblock `_, _, foo = [1, 2, 3]`, — future readers of this code are noticed that this variable is out of interest.

Comment: And variables starting with `_` (including `_` itself) don't generate a warning when not being used.

Comment: @mudasobwa could you explain *"Memory is not allocated"*?

Comment: @Stefan Only `v` goes to function call stack when using `|_, v|`. For `|k, v|`, on the other hand, both key and value are taken from an array and put on the stack. ⇐ NB this is wrong.

Comment: @Stefan Oh, sorry, my bad, I messed things up with erlang/elixir. In ruby it is still accessible.

Comment: @mudasobwa very nice. May I ask one last question, how would it be possible to implement an "and" string on the output of each key. Like `key1 and key2 ...`

Comment: `puts hash.select { |_, v| v == true }.keys.join(' and '`)

Comment: @mudasobwa I realised I'm getting a private method error on Fixnum with this implementation

Comment: It is impossible. The code I provided works perfectly on data you posted. Whether you have other glitches, ask about in separate question.

Answer (score 3):

```
hash.each do |k, v|
  puts k if v == true
end
```

Comment: with this implementation, how would I join an `and` string for any following key greater than one. Means: first key is true, output would be `key1` but with more than the first key to be true would be `key1 and key2 .. `

Comment: @supersize I don't get what you mean. But that sounds like a different question. If so, please ask that as an independent question on a new thread.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` and `compact` methods:

```
hash.map { |k, v| k if v }.compact
```

Comment: While your answer may still be applicable, it should be noted that `Hash#compact` is a Rails method and not a Ruby one.

Answer (score 0):

It is as simple as:

```
hash.each do |k,v|
  puts k if v
end
```

Comment: I am also a bit confused by the down vote. Maybe some feedback?